# Can I use angular/di.js with an AngulrJS 1.3.0 project?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

The new dependency injection that Volta spoke about at ng-conf and is contained here: https://github.com/angular/di.js is just what I am looking for for my AngularJS 1.3.0 project.

The problem is, it is not clear to me whether or not I can use it. There doesn't seem to be an example of using it for AngularJS v1 in the github project examples.

I came across an example using it in a Backbone project: http://teropa.info/blog/2014/03/18/using-angular-2-0-dependency-injection-in-a-backbone-app.html and I found an example of using ES6 in an AngularJS v1 project: https://github.com/mvolkmann/todo-es6/, but I can't find an example using the new DI in an Angular v1 project.

I'm confused. Any pointers?

Comment: I thinks its not possible since the current injector is tightly coupled with the angular core but it would be nice to hear from the experts.

Comment: What is your use case? I mean how and why you want to use it?

Comment: I have 2+ applications with a large number of shared modules. I would like to be able to build each application from its 'root' module, sucking in only those modules that it requires. The other reason is that I would like to minimise the future migration effort to Angular 2.0, so would ideally like to use whatever 2.0 components are available now (di, router) for new development.

Comment: The nightmare comes when you try to code angular 1 as angular 2. Those are 2 different frameworks with 2 different approaches. I like get pleasure of the process. So i develop my ng1 apps according to 1.3 style and i am happy. Like Jesus had said, let tomorrow worry about itself. And ng2 is tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe don't use di.js but instead transpile similarly styled code into valid angular 1.X syntax (during a build step)

A small example and a possible start:

```
var falafel = require('falafel');
var traceur = require('traceur');

var src =  
  '@Inject(MyService,MyOtherService)' +
  'class Thing{' +
  '  constructor(service,otherservice){' +
  '  }' +
  '}';

src = traceur.compile(src, { annotations: true });
//console.log(src);

function tryGetPath(obj, path) {
  path.split('.').forEach(function(key) {
    obj = obj && obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
}

var output = falafel(src, function(node) {
  //find `Object.defineProperty for 'annotations'`
  if (node.type === 'CallExpression' && tryGetPath(node, 'arguments.1.value') === 'annotations') {
    var injectable = tryGetPath(node, 'arguments.0.name');
    var $inject = (tryGetPath(node, 'arguments.2.properties.0.value.body.body.0.argument.elements') || [])
                       .filter(function(a){return a.callee.name === 'Inject'})  
                       .reduce(function(p,c){ p.push.apply(p,c.arguments); return p;},[])
                       .map(function(a){return "'"+a.name+"'";});
    node.update(injectable + '.$inject = [' + $inject.toString() + '];');
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Perhaps you can even use certain attributes (eg `@NgController` etc) to register it on your module as a controller.